# Cant seem to understand why SQL Query is not giving me the correct response

Tags: mysql, hive

Im trying to Print players with a salary above 500,000$ in 2002 who have made more
than 30 homeruns. i have to pull data from two tables but what i have is not working and giving me an error. I cant seem to figure out the error though and why it is not giving me the output i need.

```
SELECT batter.playerID, HR, salary_table.salary, salary_table.yearID

FROM batter, salary_table

JOIN salary_table ON salary_table.playerID = batter.playerID
JOIN salary_table ON salary_table.yearID = batter.yearID

WHERE salary_table.yearID = 2002
AND salary_table.salary > 500000
AND HR > 30
GROUP BY batter.playerID, HR, salary_table.salary, salary_table.yearID;
```

The error im getting is = AILED: SemanticException [Error 10008]: Line 5:5 Ambiguous table alias 'salary_table'

Comment: You have multiple joins with `salary_table`, you need to give them different aliases to disambiguate. You also shouldn't mix explicit `JOIN` with cross-products.

Comment: @Barmar so if i put a comma after batter.playerID and remover up to salary_table.yearID will this sort the issue out? doing this gives me the error ParseException line 5:82 cannot recognize input near '=' 'batter' '.' in table source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join with `salary_table` multiple times.

```
SELECT b.playerID, b.hr, s.salary, s.yearID
FROM batter AS b
JOIN salary_table AS s ON b.playerID = s.playerID AND b.yearID = s.yearID
WHERE s.yearID = 2002
AND s.salary > 500000
AND b.hr > 30
```

You also don't need `GROUP BY`, since you're not aggregating anything in the tables.

Comment: Oh god im stupid, i should know this being a Msc Computer science student -.- You the best man <3